# Using implicits for scala map keys

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-2.10

Can someone tell me why, as shown below, an implicit conversion works when simply creating a KeyVal object but does not work when creating a key in a Map that is a KeyVal.

Thank you.

```
object o {
  case class KeyVal(i: Int)
  object KeyVal {
    implicit def strToKeyVal(s:String) = KeyVal(s.toInt)
  }
}

import o._

val x : KeyVal = "1"  // Works fine to create a KeyVal

val x : Map[KeyVal, String] = Map("1" -> "One") // Type Mismatch: found (String, String), wants (KeyVal, String)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala compiler is not an allmighty thing, and it cant resolve all types of type errors. How should it convert `(String, String)` tuple to `(KeyVal, String)` tuple and why not to `(String, KeyVal)` or `(KeyVal, KeyVal)`. Your implicit conversion converts `String` to `KeyVal`, but not a `(String, String)` to `KeyVal`. If you add this implicit conversion to the companion object:

```
implicit def strToKeyVal(s: (String, String)): (KeyVal, String) = (KeyVal(s._1.toInt), s._2)
```

everything would work fine

Comment: Thanks.  I guess expecting it to know that only the first member of the Tuple needs to be converted was too much.  However I didn't think it was that unreasonable since it should know that the first member of the Tuple was a KeyVal since the value was a Map[KeyVal,String]

Answer (score 3):

It's just a matter of timing. By the time the type of the `Map` is considered, you no longer have a `String`, but a `(String, String)` tuple. This happens because `->` is an operator that is applied first, and then its result is returned for `Map`.

If you avoid using that operator, it works:

```
val x : Map[KeyVal, String] = Map(("1", "One"))
```

Comment: That makes sense.  An alternative I came up with was to use an implicit class KeyVal(s: String) that has a method: def holds(contents: String) = (this -> contents)  
Then the map can be defined as Map[KeyVal, String] = Map("1" holds "One").  That works for me since the KeyVal is actually wells on a plate so it's saying that the well holds some contents.  Thanks to all for the good answers.